# Manually set Culture Info Year Time Pattern

Tags: asp.net, datetime, currentculture

I would like to ask if it is a good coding practice to manually set the `YearMonthPattern` of the `CurrentCulture`? My problem is I set the current culture to `Invariant`, and the `YearMonthPattern` changed.

What I did is just added the code to set the `YearMonthPattern` just after setting the Cultures.

```
//Set Cultures
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo(127);
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo(127);
//Set Year Month Pattern
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.YearMonthPattern = "MMMM, yyyy";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't see anything wrong with it. It's just that it might not be conform to the actual culture pattern but if that's how you want years to be displayed it is OK.

Comment: Thanks Darin. Before I'm not setting the Cultures, and by default it was set to `English (United States)`. But I got issue when I'm not setting the cultures, so I came up with initializing it and found this `Invariant Culture` (which I think is the default one). And later, this `YearTimePattern` was changed. I guess I'll stick with my code above. Thanks :D